# How to make a pub/restaurant/club or whatever finder app work without entering GPS of location?

Tags: android, gps

I want to make a public location finder in android. One way is to enter the GPS coords of locations. But, is there any service or whatever that can do that for me, so I can hook up my code to it? To be honest I don't understand how location finder apps works....

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapView.setSatellite(false);
mapView.setStreetView(true);
mapController = mapView.getController();
mapController.setZoom(13);
getLastLocation();
animateToCurrentLocation();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API & location services can do this and even more. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/
https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

It's possible to get precise location even without GPS as  google collects location data about Wi-Fi spots and GSM towers and then uses this information in location services.